# Porting a Lazarus Application from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, lazarus

I developed a small Open Source application to help me in my doctoral thesis. The application works correctly on Windows. When I try to run on Linux everything works perfectly well, but when I closed the application I received This message:

```
Project SmCube raised exception class ´External: SIGSEGV´.
```

I have tried to run some example applications (that came with Lazarus by default) and they are running ok.

I have tried to trace the problem. After the   "Application.Terminate" command the debug stuck on this routine:

```
{------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Method: TGtk2WidgetSet.AppWaitMessage
  Params:  None
  Returns: Nothing

  Passes execution control to the GTK engine till something happens
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure TGtk2WidgetSet.AppWaitMessage;
begin
  WaitingForMessages:=true;
  if not FGtkTerminated then
  begin
    {$IFDEF USE_GTK_MAIN_OLD_ITERATION}
    gtk_main_iteration_do(True);
    {$ELSE}
DEBUG STOPS HERE --> g_main_context_iteration(g_main_context_default, True);
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
  WaitingForMessages:=false;
end;
```

Please, someone can help me discover what is happening?
Best regards

Comment: No possible way anyone can help without seeing some code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @John3136, but I thought it was a specific problem with Larazus and Linux ;)

Comment: Did you experienced such problem with empty project? Did you try to debug your project? What versions of FPC/Lazarus/Linux you are using? What packages you are using in the your project? There is a lot of info that you missed in the your question.

Comment: A more complete traceback would also help. Anyway, an application that seems to work fine is no guarantee that the application is correct. Your problem is not about porting windows to linux, but how to spot behaviour that may, depending on the circumstances cause problems. (circumstances loosely defined as a different implementation of an API)

Comment: Hi folks I edited the question. Please if you can help me. ;)

Comment: Hi @Marco van de Voort can you help me?

Comment: Hi @Abelisto can you help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a specialist in the "entrails" of Lazarus. Ask you question at the [Lazarus forum](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php) - there's much more gurus. Also provide some additional info: versions of FPC/Lasarus, used packages/components. Also clarify the way and behavior to reproduce the error: is it happens always for just start/close app or it happens after some manipulations. I would in your place started at the disabling the connection to DB...

Comment: Thank you so much @Abelisto

Answer (score -1):

I also don't see enough information to give any worthwhile answer.

But I would suggest trying to compile the lazarus app with qt widgetset instead of gtk widgetset and see if it still happens.